# JQuery: select using markup tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-parsing

I am dynamically finding the string of open tag within a page and want to use JQuery to get the text of the element that the open tag corresponds to.

For example, suppose this is my page:

```
<h1 class="articleHeadline">
  <NYT_HEADLINE  version="1.0" type=" ">
    The Arab Awakening and Israel
  </NYT_HEADLINE>
</h1> 
<author id="monkey" class="mainauthorstyle"> 
  <h6 class="byline">
    By 
    <a rel="author" href="http://topics.nytimes.com/top/opinion/editorialsandoped
    /oped/columnists/thomaslfriedma/index.html?inline=nyt-per" title="More Articles
    by Thomas L.Friedman" class="meta-per">
      THOMAS L. FRIEDMAN
    </a>
  </h6> 
</author>
```

I find the `'<author id="monkey" class= "mainauthorstyle">'` open tag string, and want to get `$("author" id["monkey"] class["mainauthorstyle"]).text()` --> `By THOMAS L. FRIEDMAN`. Is there a simple way to turn the open tag markup into a selector? Should I just parse it with regex?

Edit: I don't know beforehand what element I want.  My code looks through the page and comes up with `'<author id="monkey" class= "mainauthorstyle">'` as the beginning of the element. I don't know the literal beforehand.  I run this code on arbitrary webpages.

Comment: Take some time and format your question.  Show some investment in the community if you're going to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

`author#monkey.mainauthorstyle`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/MgbCX/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your question.  If you just want the text, use the following:

```
$("author#monkey.mainauthorstyle").text();
```

If you want to select the element only if "THOMAS L. FRIEDMAN" is the author, then:

```
$("author#monkey.mainauthorstyle:contains('THOMAS L. FRIEDMAN')")
// See http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ for more info on the :contains() selector
```

---

UPDATED AFTER YOUR EDIT:

If you are able to determine that you want to select the "text" of the author element with id of "monkey" and class of "mainauthorstyle", you simply need to build a jQuery selector out of those bits of information.  From there you can use the text() or html() methods on the resulting jQuery object to get the contents of that element.

As my example above showed:

```
$("author#monkey.mainauthorstyle").text();
```

or
    $("author#monkey.mainauthorstyle").html();

Note that the selector used is probably overkill as you should be able to simply select the element by its id.

```
$("#monkey").text();
```